# xpath for xml to get node information

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am writing a java program to search for text and return its node information.

1. The program should search for text anywhere in the document and.
2. Return 5 predefined node and node-values.

Sample xml file : -

```
<project xmlns="https://example.hoom/go/bing">
    <name>purchaseOrder </name>
    <property name="included" type="hidden">true</property>
    <locales>
        <locale>en</locale>
        <locale>hi</locale>
    </locales>
    <defaultLocale>en</defaultLocale>
    <gamespace>
        <name locale="en">hambook</name>
        <name locale="de">hambook</name>
        <lastChanged>2014-03-05T18:47:30</lastChanged>
        <lastChangedBy>userx</lastChangedBy>
        <property name="included" type="hidden">true</property>
        <gamespace>
            <name locale="en">DbBook</name>
            <name locale="zw">DbBook</name>
            <hecrotSubject status="valid">
                <name locale="en">hexValue</name>
                <name locale="zw">hexValue</name>
                <hecrotItem>
                    <name locale="en">hireValue</name>
                    <name locale="zw">hireValue</name>
                    <hello>searchTerm</hello>
                </hecrotItem>
            </hecrotSubject>
        </gamespace>
    </gamespace>
    <gamespace>
        <name locale="en">Names</name>
        <lastChanged>2016-01-12T12:42:46</lastChanged>
        <gamespace>
            <name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
            <name locale="zw">Database Layer</name>
            <hecrotSubject status="valid">
                <name locale="en">qsxyz</name>
                <hecrotItem>
                    <name locale="en">myName</name>
                    <hello>...Hi there..</hello>
                </hecrotItem>
            </hecrotSubject>
        </gamespace>
    </gamespace>
</project>
```

My current xpath is :-

```
"//*[local-name()='gamespace']/*[local-name()='hecrotSubject']/*[local-name()='hecrotItem'][contains(., '"& searchTerm &"')]/ancestor-or-self::*/*[local-name()='name' and @locale='en']"
```

Which is giving only the root tag using `xpath.compile().evaluate()`.
While result I need is

name value of five predefined nodes if they contain the search text (searchTerm in this sample xml).

sample result should be:-

> Project - purchaseOrder
>
> gamespace - hambook
>
> gamespace - DbBook
>
> hecrotSubject - hexValue
>
> hecrotItem - hireValue

**Edit**

I am using following statements in java : -

```
String expression = Xpath;
Strings vals = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);
System.out.println(vals);
```

Comment: what did you done already? where are you stuck?

Comment: I am using followin statement in java : - 
String expression = Xpath;
Strings vals = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);
System.out.println(vals);

Comment: you have invalid xpath query (checked via xmlspy), for get name ```/project/gamespace/name```, get hecroSubject: ```/project/gamespace/gamespace/hecrotSubject```

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/a/36004249/1511077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why you get only the *root tag*.
But in your xpaht the case of some values (node names) are wrong. Fixing hecrotSubject and  hecrotItem and it should work.
But by the way I do not see why you are using local-name with setting up the right name-space  something like the following should also do:

```
/b:gamespace/b:hecrotsubject/b:hecrotitem[contains(., 'searchTerm')]/ancestor-or-self::*/b:name[@locale='en']"
```

**Update doe to updated question**

The main problem is that you need iterate over the `NodeList` which could be returned by xpath `evaluate`.

Have a look to e.g.: [How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2811101/2115381)

Comment: I am using followin statement in java : - 
String expression = Xpath;
Strings vals = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);
System.out.println(vals);

Comment: And it prints only one value

Comment: @user2816085: Please consider that the return value from evaluate() may be an array.

Comment: the expression returns string as trying to initialize array gives error
String[] vals = expression; not working

Comment: Thanks a lot I need to iterate for nodes